# Jackson's XmlMapper Change Default Naming Convertor

Tags: java, xml, jackson

With the help of Jackson, I want to do some serializing/deserializing by reusing some existing XML/classes with no Jackson annotations.

Is it possible to change default Jackson's XmlMapper field naming mapping configuration to map all tags/fields like that "firstName->FirstName" without introducing any annotations?

I mean these class fields (note: they start with small letter)

```
class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName; 
}
```

to map to that XML (note: they start with the capital letter):

```
<Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
</Person>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just found that we have naming strategy for that purpose:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
```